# Less pass mixins/variables into rest parameter

Tags: css, less

I want .centerChildren to be passed from text-controls. How do I do this?

```
.centerChildren() {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.progressBar(@rest...) {
  .jp-progress {
    ...
    @{rest...} //Something like this
  }
}
.jp-text-controls {
  .progressBar(.centerChildren)
}
```

Comment: No, you can't pass a mixin as a parameter to another function.

Comment: Related (or possible duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721356/less-how-can-i-pass-a-mixin-as-an-argument-to-another-mixin/41722581#41722581